# R won't reference/can't find a compiled loaded C Code

Tags: c, r, statistics

I've created a new Robust HoltWinters function (based on the stats::Holt-Winters) method in R (per "Robust Forecasting with Exponential and Holt-Winters
Smoothing" by Sarah Gelper1,, Roland Fried, Christophe Croux. September 26, 2008.)  Why? Well...why not! But I digress...

The core of the stats::Holt-Winters method is a C code called [C_HoltWinters](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/src/HoltWinters.c), which I've modified to be robust (See below)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>  // memcpy
#include <math.h>

#include <R.h>
#include "ts.h"

void HoltWinters (
          double *x, /*as.double(x) */
          double *x_adj, /*Adjust time series data, if need be                   Added*/
          int    *xl, /*lenx - Length of the current time series*/
          double *alpha, /*as.double(max(min(alpha, 1), 0)), */
          double *beta, /*as.double(max(min(beta,1), 0)), */
          double *gamma, /*as.double(max(min(gamma, 1), 0)), */ 
          double *llamda,/*as.double(max(min(llamda,1),0)),                     ADDED*/
          int    *start_time, /*as.integer(start.time),  */
          int    *seasonal, /*as.integer(!+(seasonal == "multiplicative")), */
          int    *period, /* as.integer(f),  */
          int    *dotrend, /* as.integer(!is.logical(beta) || beta),  */
          int    *doseasonal, /* as.integer(!is.logical(gamma) || gamma), */

          double *a, /*l.start - starting values for level*/
          double *b, /*b.start - starting values for Trend*/
          double *s, /*s.start - starting values for SEasonal*/
          double *l, /*t.start - starting values for LLamda                      ADDED*/
          double *k, /* Value for K                                              ADDED*/
          double *ck, /*value for ck                                             ADDED*/
          /* return values */
          double *SSE,
          double *level,
          double *trend,
          double *season

    )

{
    double res = 0, xhat = 0, stmp = 0, theta = 1, RhoK = 0, phi = 0 ;
    int i, i0, s0; /*i is the current t, i0 is the current LESS starting period, and s0 = is the seasonal current LESS Starting period*/

    /* copy start values to the beginning of the vectors */
    level[0] = *a;
    if (*dotrend == 1) trend[0] = *b;
    if (*doseasonal == 1) memcpy(season, s, *period * sizeof(double));

    for (i = *start_time - 1; i < *xl; i++) {
    /* indices for period i */
    i0 = i - *start_time + 2;
    s0 = i0 + *period - 1;

    /* forecast *for* period i */
    xhat = level[i0 - 1] + (*dotrend == 1 ? trend[i0 - 1] : 0);

    stmp = *doseasonal == 1 ? season[s0 - *period] : (*seasonal != 1);


    if (*seasonal == 1)
        xhat += stmp;
    else
        xhat *= stmp;

    /* Sum of Squared Errors */
    res   = x[i] - xhat;

    /*adjusting for robustness....Gahds*/
    RhoK = (abs(res / theta) <= *k ? *ck * (1 - pow(1 - pow((res / (*k * theta)),2),3)): *ck);
    theta = sqrt(*llamda * RhoK * pow(theta,2) + (1 - *llamda) * pow(theta,2));
    phi = (abs(res / theta) < *k ? res / theta : ((res / theta) / abs(res / theta) * (*k)));
    x_adj[i] = phi * theta + xhat;

    res = x_adj[i] - xhat;

    *SSE += res * res;

    /* estimate of level *in* period i */
    if (*seasonal == 1)
        level[i0] = *alpha       * (x_adj[i] - stmp)
              + (1 - *alpha) * (level[i0 - 1] + trend[i0 - 1]);
    else
        level[i0] = *alpha       * (x_adj[i] / stmp)
              + (1 - *alpha) * (level[i0 - 1] + trend[i0 - 1]);

    /* estimate of trend *in* period i */
    if (*dotrend == 1)
        trend[i0] = *beta        * (level[i0] - level[i0 - 1])
              + (1 - *beta)  * trend[i0 - 1];

    /* estimate of seasonal component *in* period i */
    if (*doseasonal == 1) {
        if (*seasonal == 1)
        season[s0] = *gamma       * (x_adj[i] - level[i0])
               + (1 - *gamma) * stmp;
        else
        season[s0] = *gamma       * (x_adj[i] / level[i0])
               + (1 - *gamma) * stmp;
    }
    }
}
```

So I compile it, in windows *sigh*, with R (3.2.2):

```
R CMD SHLIB C_R_HoltWinters.c
gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c C_R_HoltWinters.c -o C_R_HoltWinters.o
gcc -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o C_R_HoltWinters.dll tmp.def C_R_HoltWinters.o -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64 -lR
```

Load it into R:

```
dyn.load('C_R_HoltWinters.dll')
```

Checking to see if it's there

```
    > getLoadedDLLs()
                                                                                     Filename Dynamic.Lookup
base                                                                                     base          FALSE
utils                           C:/Program Files/RRO/R-3.2.2/library/utils/libs/x64/utils.dll          FALSE
methods                     C:/Program Files/RRO/R-3.2.2/library/methods/libs/x64/methods.dll          FALSE
RevoUtilsMath   C:/Program Files/RRO/R-3.2.2/library/RevoUtilsMath/libs/x64/RevoUtilsMath.dll           TRUE
grDevices               C:/Program Files/RRO/R-3.2.2/library/grDevices/libs/x64/grDevices.dll          FALSE
graphics                  C:/Program Files/RRO/R-3.2.2/library/graphics/libs/x64/graphics.dll          FALSE
stats                           C:/Program Files/RRO/R-3.2.2/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll          FALSE
tools                           C:/Program Files/RRO/R-3.2.2/library/tools/libs/x64/tools.dll          FALSE
internet                                    C:/PROGRA~1/RRO/R-32~1.2/modules/x64/internet.dll           TRUE
(embedding)                                                                       (embedding)          FALSE
C_R_HoltWinters                                              C:/scripts/R/C_R_HoltWinters.dll           TRUE
```

Ah, yup, there it is. So, just for poops and chuckles I run a test on it:

```
 > is.loaded('C_R_HoltWinters')
[1] FALSE
> is.loaded("C_R_HoltWinters")
[1] FALSE
> is.loaded(C_R_HoltWinters)
Error in is.loaded(C_R_HoltWinters) : object 'C_R_HoltWinters' not found
```

Okay....it should be there but it's not. Maybe it knows something I don't so I try to run it:

```
> .C("C_R_HoltWinters", blahblahblah)
    Error in .C("C_R_HoltWinters") : 
      C symbol name "C_R_HoltWinters" not in load table
> .Call("C_R_HoltWinters", blahblahblah)
    Error in .Call("C_R_HoltWinters") : 
      C symbol name "C_R_HoltWinters" not in load table
```

But when I load a different c code called foo and run it, it runs fine.

Why isn't R able to reference C_R_HoltWinters.dll? Will this also break if I put it into a package?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing, executed just fine

Comment: That's really weird. Can you find this HoltWinters in the output of your `getLoadedDLLs()`? On another note, if you're thinking about using this code in a package, I *strongly* suggest looking at Rcpp, as it makes easier to navigate the mess that external calls are in R.

Comment: Hm. I have compiled your C code here, removing the `#include "ts.h"` line. It successfully `dyn.loads`, shows up in the `getLoadedDLLs()`, but when I check if it `is.loaded`, it returns FALSE. Strange.

Comment: PS, for running it you should use the name of the function, and not the file. So it should be `.C("HoltWinters", bla bla bla)`, which is apparently running for me.

Comment: Yup, I can find the C_R_HoltWinters in getLoadedDlls(), with the value of Dynamic.Lookup = True

Comment: Made a few edits to my question to reflect what andrechalom mentioned about running "HoltWinters" instead of "HoltWinters.dll". No change to outcome of not being able to find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem here is a confusion between the symbol names (which may represent functions in C) and the shared library. After running `dyn.load('C_R_HoltWinters.dll')`, you can check that it was loaded by looking at `getLoadedDlls()`. Now, what `is.loaded` is looking for are the symbols that are defined inside this DLL. So, the following code will show you that the function "HoltWinters", defined in your C code, is available to be called from R:

```
>  is.loaded("HoltWinters")
[1] TRUE
```

And this is the function name that you should use on .C calls as well.

Comment: What got myself confused is the fact that all my shared libraries contain a function with the same name as the library itself :P

Comment: Andrechalom, yup I had messed up when posting my questions, but when I try is.loaded('C_R_HoltsWinter') is still says false.....>> is.loaded('C_R_HoltWinters')
[1] FALSE

Comment: Yes, that is actually the expected behaviour. Because "C_R_HoltWinter" is the name of the library. The name of the function, which is what you should pass to `is.loaded`, is simply "HoltWinters". Check your C code: `void HoltWinters (` etc etc. The bottom line is that "is.loaded" does not check if a *library* is loaded, it checks if a *function* is loaded ;)

Comment: Yea, the original HoltWinters in the stats package is still there. However, I modified the core c code (C_HoltWinter) and renamed it C_R_HoltWinter and compiled it so it became C_R_HoltWinters.dll So there are now two compiled c codes. I have to import/load/bring into r the newly compiled code: C_R_HoltWinter.dll. All is well until I try to run C_R_HoltWinters with arguments passed to it, that is hen R says it can't find the C_R_HoltWinters object. I'm not trying to run HoltWinters, nor C_HoltWinter. (And thank you for your time on this, I seriously hope I'm not being dense ;) )

Comment: Hi. The problem is that the C function that you are loading is still called "
"HoltWinters". See the C code that you have posted. You can try changing the name of your C function to `void C_R_HoltWinters`, and then your code will be called from R as `C_R_HoltWinters`.

Comment: There it is. Yup, just me being dense! Thank you for your help! So R was trying to reference the C FUNCTION, not the Script.